# Solving $2-2\sin^2(x)-\frac{3}{2}\sin(2x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve this equation(preparation for exam).

$2-2\sin^2(x)-\frac{3}{2}\sin(2x)=0$

I have a idea to convert all sin function to "x", and the solve it using quadratic equation, but I am not sure how to do it, because, here I have two different sin function $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(2x)$.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Expand $\sin(2x)$ with the formula of double angle.

Comment: Then I have $3*\sin(x)*\cos(x)$, and what I can to with that :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can make the substitution $\sin^2{x}=(1-\cos^2{x})$ and $\sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}$ therefore simplifying the equation down to:

$$ 2-2(1-\cos^2{x})-\frac{3}{2}(2\sin{x}\cos{x})=0$$
further simplifying to:
$$ 2\cos^2{x}-3\sin{x}\cos{x} =0$$

which you can then factorise to obtain the solution like you would with an equation of the form $x(x-a)=0$ that gives solution $x=0$ and $x=a$:
$$\cos{x}\;(2\cos{x}-3\sin{x})=0$$

Since we know that a solution to the above factored expression is when $\cos{x}=0$ since if substituted back into the expression it would be $ 0\times(2\cos{x}-3\sin{x}) $ and obviously anything multiplied by zero gives zero, so we know that $\cos{x}=0$ is a solution. We can do this similarly to $(2\cos{x}-3\sin{x})$ since whenever this is zero the expression is also true since it would be $\cos{x}\times 0$ which is obviously zero and therefore satisfies out expression.

Therefore we proceed by solving the two equations: 
$$\cos{x}=0 \;\;\text{and} \;\;(2\cos{x}-3\sin{x})=0$$

Normally when you get these questions there is a restriction on the value of $x$ (e.g. $0<x<2\pi$) since by the nature of trigonometric functions they tend to repeat themselves and thus there are often infinite solutions for $x$. But if there isn't a restriction one solve it as follows:
$\cos{x}=0$ gives solutions 
$$ x=\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi \;\; \text{where }n \text{ is an integer}$$

likewise for
 $$(2\cos{x}-3\sin{x})=0 \rightarrow \tan{x}=\frac{2}{3}$$
we attain solutions:
$$ x=\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{3}} +n \pi$$
so the general answer is:
$$ x=\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi \text{  and  }x=\tan^{-1}{\frac{2}{3}} +n \pi  $$
if the question did indeed say that $x$ was restricted all you would have to do is put in integer values of $n$ like $-1,1,2,...$ into the above solutions and find those values of $x$ that satisfy the restriction (like for the example those $x$ that are less than $2\pi$ but are greater than $0$)

Comment: $\sin x^2\ne\sin^2 x=(\sin x)^2$, edit!

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thanks for spotting that, I'm so used to inputting things into Mathematica where one would type Sin[x]^2 for $\sin^2{x}$ where's if you do that in LaTeX it obviously comes out incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand what have you written here, I dont understand how I can solve $cosx(2cosx−3sinx)=0$

Comment: if you had an equation of the form $x(x-a)=0$ do you see that the solution are $x=0$ and $x=a$ since we just set each factor to be zero, that is: $x=0$ and $(x-a)=0 \rightarrow x=a$?

Comment: This case is similar in that we set each factor of $\cos{x}(2\cos{x}-3\sin{x})=0$ equal to zero: that is we can have $\cos{x}=0$ and $(2\cos{x}-3\sin{x})=0$. So we must solve those two equations to find the solutions to the original problem. I will extend my answer to show it in a little more detail.